# How do I access only the first element of data in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

So, I have the following View Model where I fetch the data:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Alamofire


class AllStatsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    @Published var stats = [CountryStats]()

    func fetchGlobalStats() {
        let request = AF.request("https://projectcovid.deadpool.wtf/all")
       request.responseDecodable(of: AllCountryStats.self) { (response) in
         guard let globalStats = response.value else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.stats = globalStats.data
        }

        self.isLoading = false
       }
    }
}
```

And this is the view:

```
struct CardView: View {
    @ObservedObject var allStatsVM = AllStatsViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.allStatsVM.stats[0].country)

        }


        .onAppear {
            self.allStatsVM.fetchGlobalStats()
        }
    }

}
```

I'd like to access only the first element of the data, but the problem I face is that when the view loads, the data is not loaded, so I get an index out of range error at

```
Text(self.allStatsVM.stats[0].country)
```

Is there a way, I can access the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
struct CardView: View {
    @ObservedObject var allStatsVM = AllStatsViewModel()



      var body: some View {
            VStack {
                if self.allStatsVM.stats.count > 0 {
                    Text(self.allStatsVM.stats[0].country)
                } else {
                    Text ("data loading")
                }

        }


        .onAppear {
            self.allStatsVM.fetchGlobalStats()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, when I go home from the app, and I reopen the it always shows data loading. But when I switch to a different tab (it's embedded in a tab view), I again get the data. Is there some way I can make it persistent?

Comment: yes ...there are ways. but what i don't understand is: you are using core data, am i right? normally core data is blazingly fast ...so is you db that big? you could e.g. cache your data so that you just save the data your user sees when he exits the app and load only these data when he starts again while you are loading the "real" data in background...